# React - Passing callbacks from React Context consumers to providers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have the following context

```
import React, { createContext, useRef } from "react";

const ExampleContext = createContext(null);

export default ExampleContext;

export function ExampleProvider({ children }) {
  const myMethod = () => {
  };

  return (
    <ExampleContext.Provider
      value={{
        myMethod,
      }}
    >
      {children}
      <SomeCustomComponent 
         /* callback={callbackPassedFromConsumer} */
      />
    </ExampleContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

As you can see, it renders a custom component which receive a method as prop. This method is defined in a specific screen, which consumes this context.

How can I pass it from the screen to the provider?

This is how I consume the context (with a HOC):

```
import React from "react";

import ExampleContext from "../../../contexts/ExampleContext";

const withExample = (Component) => (props) =>
  (
    <ExampleContext.Consumer>
      {(example) => (
        <Component {...props} example={example} />
      )}
    </ExampleContext.Consumer>
  );

export default withExample;
```

And this is the screen where I have the method which I need to pass to the context provider

```
function MyScreen({example}) {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const myMethodThatINeedToPass = () => {
       ...
       setData([]);
       ...
    }

    return (<View>
      ...
    </View>);
}

export default withExample(MyScreen);
```

### Update:

I am trying to do this because in my real provider I have a BottomSheet component which renders two buttons "Delete" and "Report". This component is reusable, so, in order to avoid repeating myself, I am using a context provider.

See: https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet/issues/259

Then, as the bottom sheet component which is rendered in the provider can receive optional props "onReportButtonPress" or "onDeleteButtonPress", I need a way to pass the method which manipulates my stateful data inside the screen (the consumer) to the provider.

Comment: I think that this is against of idea data flow in react, but I will try to solve this issue

Comment: why do u think that? @Jan

Comment: Because SomeCustomComponent will render first, and then MyScreen

Comment: I am really  curious why do you need such a relation between two components

Comment: @Jan check the update, I explain it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, in React the data only [flows down](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#the-data-flows-down).

> This is commonly called a “top-down” or “unidirectional” data flow. Any state is always owned by some specific component, and any data or UI derived from that state can only affect components “below” them in the tree.

Your callbacks ("onReportButtonPress", "onDeleteButtonPress") must be available at provider's scope.

```
<ExampleContext.Provider
  value={{
    onReportButtonPress,
    onDeleteButtonPress,
  }}
>
  {children}
</ExampleContext.Provider>;
```

Comment: The thing is that both methods are defined inside the consumer, because they have to manipulate its respective states.

Comment: As stated in the answer, if you want it to work as you describing, they need to be defined in providers scope

Answer (score 0):

Render SomeCustomComponent in Consumer component. This is the React way of doing things :)

Comment: If u r not busy, feel free to check this other thread where I explain everything better. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68476236/reactjs-component-with-optional-props-inside-react-context