# ReactJS - Component with optional props inside React Context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my app, there is a [bottom sheet](https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet) in the top level of my navigation system. As it is showed/hidden when the user interacts with the elements of other deeper screens inside the navigation system, I have had to wrap it inside a React Context. Take a look at this [idea](https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet/issues/259).

Now, imagine that this context is rendering my custom bottom sheet component:

```
function MessageOptions({ onDeleteButtonPress, onReportButtonPress, ... }) {
    ... 
    
    const handleOnDeleteButtonPress = () => {
      ...
      onDeleteButtonPress?.();
    }

    const handleOnReportButtonPress = () => {
      ...
      onReportButtonPress?.();
    }

    ...

    return (
      <View style={globalStyles.overlayed} pointerEvents="box-none">
        <OptionsBottomSheet
          ref={menuRef}
          snapPoints={[155, 0]}
          initialSnap={1}
          topItems={getTopItems()}
          bottomItems={getBottomItems()}
          onCloseEnd={onCloseEnd}
        />
      </View>
    );
}
```

As you can see, it is receiving two optional props, "onDeleteButtonPress" and "onReportButtonPress".

My idea is to consume the context which renders this custom bottom sheet component, in  all my chat bubbles, just to open the bottom sheet when they are long pressed.

This is the context provider:

```
import React, { createContext, useRef } from "react";

import useStateWithCallback from "../../hooks/useStateWithCallback";
import MessageOptions from "../../components/Messaging/Options/MessageOptions";

const MessageOptionsContext = createContext(null);

export default MessageOptionsContext;

export function MessageOptionsProvider({ children }) {
  ...

  return (
    <MessageOptionsContext.Provider
      value={{
        open,
        close,
      }}
    >
      {children}
      <MessageOptions
        ref={messageOptionsRef}
        message={message}
        // onReportButtonPress={onReportButtonPress}
        // onDeleteButtonPress={onDeleteButtonPress}
        onCloseEnd={handleOnCloseEnd}
      />
    </MessageOptionsContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

When the user presses the delete button, I will be removing the specific message from the screen's messages list state.

**How can I pass the methods from the parent (ChatScreen) of the consumer (Bubble) to the provider (MessageOptionsProvider)?**

This is the flow of my app:

```
ChatScreen --> (contains the messages list (array) state)
    |
    |
    ---> BubbleList
             |
             |
             ---> Bubble (consumes the bottom sheet context)
```

I am doing this to avoid repeating my self in different routes of my app, but for being transparent, I am a little stuck in this use case.

Any ideas? It seems to be impossible?